# Web video: load just a clip from a large video

Tags: video, web, html5-video, flash-video

I am working in a web application for controlling a device that records large videos (~12 hours / ~3 GB) and I am interested in **loading** just a clip of one of those videos into *any* web-embeddable video player (I don't care about the technology as long as it is cross-browser). The thing is that users may play clips of large videos and I'd like to prevent them from loading unnecessary footage. Is this even possible?